# How To Filter Data In Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have a problem with my code , i want to filter by in 2 category . but in the work i did , just filter with one category can work , and filter with other category didnt work. anyone can help me to solve this ?

and this is my controller

```
public function index($state = null , $category = null)
{
    if (!empty($state)) {
    $this->load->model('M_kegiatan');
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->get_status($state);
    $this->load->view('beranda', $data); 
    }else if (!empty($category)) { 
    $this->load->model('M_kegiatan');
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->get_kategori($category);
    $this->load->view('beranda', $data);
} else {

    $this->load->model('M_kegiatan');
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->get_kegiatan();
    $this->load->view('beranda', $data);
}
```

this is my model :

```
    public function get_status($status) {
    $this->db->order_by('tanggal','desc');
    $this->db->where('status',$status);
    $query = $this->db->get('kegiatan');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query -> result();
    }
}
    public function get_kategori ($kategori) {
    $this->db->order_by('tanggal','desc');
    $this->db->where('kategori',$kategori);
    $query = $this->db->get('kegiatan');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query -> result();
    }
}
```

from this code , just filter by get_status () can work , anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public function index($state = null, $category = null)
{
    $this->load->model('M_kegiatan');
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if (!empty($state) || !empty ($category))
    { 
        $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->get_filtered($state, $category);
    }
    else 
   {
        $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->get_kegiatan();
   }
   $this->load->view('beranda', $data);
}
```

Add this function to the model

```
public function get_filtered ($status, $category) 
{
   $this->db->order_by('tanggal','desc');

   If (!empty($status))
   {
     $this->db->where('status',$status);
   }

   If (!empty($category))
   {
      $this->db->where('kategori',$category);
   }

   $query = $this->db->get('kegiatan');
   return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : NULL;
```